# Linq to XMl sorting method

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi I have a datagridview which binds XML manually.

I wish to sort out the columns by clicking column header.

here is the method i wrote: when you click column header, it grabs column header and sorting data by that column header.

I also put a toggle switch(direction) on that, so when user click again , the data can be sorted in different orders ( ascending/ descending)

```
public BindingSource BindXML(string file, string headerName, bool direction)
        {
            XElement record = XElement.Load(file);
            var q = from r in record.Descendants("record")
                    //ascending order?
                    orderby (string)r.Element(headerName)
                    select new
                    {
                        work_pack = (int)r.Element("work_pack"),
                        Locational_Details = (string)r.Element("Locational_Details"),
                        RegimeName = (string)r.Element("RegimeName")
                    };
            if (direction)
            {
                //descending order
                q.OrderByDescending(r => r);
            }

           return new BindingSource(q, null);}
```

The problem is the lambda expression `q.OrderByDescending(r => r);` doesn't work at all

i even tried `q.OrderByDescending(r => r.RegimeName)`

and  `q.OrderByDescending(r => r.Element(headerName));`

Neither of them works. Any help on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unlike `List<T>.Sort()` the `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy()` is NOT an in-place sort.
Change your code to  `q = q.OrderByDescending(r => r.HeaderName);`  and it should work